# Refit with TestServer and NSubstitute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nsubstitute, .net-5, refit

I am trying to use Refit to test a Rest interface on TestServer, while replacing the DateTime.Now to return custom time.

My refit interface looks something like this:

```
public interface IMyApi
    {
        DateTime CurentTime();
        [Get("/api/...")]
        Task<ApiResponse<DateTime>> SomeOtherFunction();
    }
```

and in my implementation, I have

```
public class MyApi {
  public virtual DateTime CurrentTime { return DateTime.Now; } 
  ...
  public async Task<IActionResult> SomeOtherFunction() { return CurrentTime();  }
}
```

This works fine as a Unit test

```
var myMock = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyApi>();
myMock.Configure().CurrentTime().Returns(..some fixed date..);
myMock.SomeOtherFunction();
// returns the fixed date
```

However I am missing how to get this to work when I create the twin using Refit and running on TestServer, since the original function keeps getting called:

```
var myMock = Substitute.ForPartsOf<IMyApi>();
myMock.Configure().CurrentTime().Returns(..some fixed date..);
var myServer = new TestServer(builder: ... );

// how do I connect to the invokation below?
var client = RestService.For<IMyApi>(myServer.CreateClient());
client.SomeOtherFunction();
```

So question is, how do I have the RestService.For<> created out of the mocked API rather than the original api? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Is this question about ASP.NET (Framework) or ASP.NET Core? You've tagged both.

Comment: Net framework 5, (nee Core). sorry. I wasn't aware there was a usage difference, hence the mistake. I removed those tags and replaced with asp.net5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that we need to replace the controller that is created at run time by the controller factory. The easiest way I have found to do this is:

1. In "ConfigureServices" of Startup class, tell the framework to store the controller in the services collection. Mine now looks somewhat like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices()
                  .AddOtherThings(...)                                                       );
            ...
         }
```

2. Replace the controller with the mocked controller, somwewhere where you can get to the controller collection (such as in WebHostBuilder's ConfigureTestServices()):

```
    var toRemove = svc.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(MyApi));
    svc.Remove(toRemove);


    var c = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyApi>(new object[] { ...constructor params... });
    svc.AddScoped(controller => c);
    controller.Configure().CurrentTime().Returns(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2001 10:00:00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game here, but have you tried using RefitSettings. Here's an example with MockHttpMessageHandler. I've used this to mock out Refit injections before.

```
using var mockHttp = new MockHttpMessageHandler(); 
var settings = new RefitSettings { HttpMessageHandlerFactory = () => mockHttp };            
var apiServiceMock = RestService.For<IRealTimePayment>("https://api.github.com", settings);
```